# g++: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

After building and installing [custom library](https://github.com/dpirch/libfvad) I try rebuild [example code](https://github.com/dpirch/libfvad/blob/master/examples/fvadwav.c).
It contains links to `/usr/include/sndfile.h` (`#include <sndfile.h>`) that exists and contian virtual functions like `sf_read_double`

part of `sndfile.h`:

```
sf_count_t  sf_read_double  (SNDFILE *sndfile, double *ptr, sf_count_t items) ;
```

I try

```sh
cp examples/fvadwav.c ~/tmp_proj/
g++ -v -g fvadwav.c
```

and get an error:

```sh
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE fvadwav.c -quiet -dumpbase fvadwav.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase fvadwav -g -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccxmJrHK.s
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) version 8.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8
 /usr/include/c++/8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) version 8.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 27ae9a20c27efba91196488dcf7713bb
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccNkTGt2.o /tmp/ccxmJrHK.s
GNU ассемблер, версия 2.30 (x86_64-linux-gnu); используется BFD версии (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc5K4mhk.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../.. /tmp/ccNkTGt2.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/ccNkTGt2.o: In function `process_sf(SNDFILE_tag*, Fvad*, unsigned long, SNDFILE_tag**, _IO_FILE*)':
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:38: undefined reference to `sf_read_double'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:44: undefined reference to `fvad_process'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:57: undefined reference to `sf_write_double'
/tmp/ccNkTGt2.o: In function `main':
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:114: undefined reference to `fvad_new'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:126: undefined reference to `fvad_set_mode'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:179: undefined reference to `sf_open'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:181: undefined reference to `sf_strerror'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:190: undefined reference to `fvad_set_sample_rate'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:205: undefined reference to `sf_open'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:207: undefined reference to `sf_strerror'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:242: undefined reference to `sf_close'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:244: undefined reference to `sf_close'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:246: undefined reference to `fvad_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my `/usr/include` is:

```sh
➜  vad ll /usr/include | grep sndfile  
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  29K июн  8  2019 sndfile.h
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  13K июн  8  2019 sndfile.hh
```

`/usr/local/include`:

```sh
➜  vad ll -t /usr/local/include | head -n 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,6K янв 28 15:01 fvad.h
```

Why errors are spawning? Heading file define this functions.
How can I build this example code without errors?

---

### Update

I try compile with `-lsndfile` flag , as  Botje adviced, but still got same error. Compile with `-L/usr/include` outs the same errors as without it. 
 Even `sudo cp /usr/include/sndfile.h /usr/lib/` and `cp /usr/include/sndfile.h .` not takes an effect.

```
g++ -lsndfile -v -g fvadwav.c


GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/8
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8
 /usr/include/c++/8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) version 8.3.0 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 8.3.0, GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 4.0.1, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.19-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 27ae9a20c27efba91196488dcf7713bb
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/cc1iiaxd.o /tmp/ccjpvtRT.s
GNU ассемблер, версия 2.30 (x86_64-linux-gnu); используется BFD версии (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.30
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-g' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccpQghex.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../.. -lsndfile /tmp/cc1iiaxd.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/tmp/cc1iiaxd.o: In function `process_sf(SNDFILE_tag*, Fvad*, unsigned long, SNDFILE_tag**, _IO_FILE*)':
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:38: undefined reference to `sf_read_double'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:44: undefined reference to `fvad_process'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:57: undefined reference to `sf_write_double'
/tmp/cc1iiaxd.o: In function `main':
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:114: undefined reference to `fvad_new'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:126: undefined reference to `fvad_set_mode'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:179: undefined reference to `sf_open'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:181: undefined reference to `sf_strerror'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:190: undefined reference to `fvad_set_sample_rate'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:205: undefined reference to `sf_open'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:207: undefined reference to `sf_strerror'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:242: undefined reference to `sf_close'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:244: undefined reference to `sf_close'
/home/t4nner/proj/learning/vad/fvadwav.c:246: undefined reference to `fvad_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

Comment: Concretely, you need to **link** with libsndfile by means of the `-lsndfile` flag to g++

Comment: @Botje, it seems to what I need, but takes no effect.

Comment: Put the link flag at the end of your command, not the start

Comment: Also, your problem has nothing to do with header files or /usr/include. You need to link with libsndfile.so using that -l flag, as the linked post will tell you.

Comment: Thanks, it works ( `g++ -v -g fvadwav.c -lsndfile -lfvad` )